# Array of objects with custom index

Tags: c#

I have these two classes:

```
public class Message
{
    string Message;
    string Code;
}

public class MessageInitializer
{
    DataSet ds;
    DataRow dr;
    message[] ms;
}
```

I want to create a constructor in `MessageInitializer` like this:

```
MessageInitializer()
{
    this.ms = new Message[ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i];
        ms[(string)dr.ItemArray[0]] = (string)dr.ItemArray[1];
    }
}
```

But array's index must be `int` type. I have no idea how to work this out:

```
ms[(string)dr.ItemArray[0]] = (string)dr.ItemArray[1];
```

**Update**:

Code format is a string like this: `[001-001-001]`, so I can't convert it to integer.

Comment: try `Integer.parseInt(dr.ItemArray[0])`

Comment: thanks. but i completely forgot to say this: code format is a string like this: {001-001-001]. so i cant convert it to integer.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're looking for a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: `dr.ItemArray[0]` is code and `dr.ItemArray[1]` is message?

Comment: What string do you have in `dr.ItemArray[0]`? `{001-001-001]`?

Comment: @AseemGautam: yes. exactly.

Comment: @NikolaiSamteladze actually its: [001-001-001]. i corrected. sorry about that.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use `Array<Message>` and not `Dictionary<string, Message>`?

Comment: dear @NikolaiSamteladze:
honestly i've never heard about dictionary. i'm working on it. but i prefer the simple array[string].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to get a list of all the messages from the database, then you can use the code below. Note, `List` instead of `Array`. Easier to use and faster.

```
public class Message
{
    string Message;
    string Code;
}

public class MessageInitializer
{
    DataSet ds;
    DataRow dr;
    List<Message> ms;

    MessageInitializer()
    {
        this.ms = new List<Message>();
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i];
            ms.Add(new Message
            {
                 Code = dr.ItemArray[0].ToString(),
                 Message = dr.ItemArray[1].ToString(),
            });
        }
    }
}
```

You mentioned that you have couple million records. `List` will perform fine in case you want to access items sequestially. If you want to access items in a non-sequential manner, I suggest you use `Dictionary` instead (to improve search perfromance):

```
public class MessageInitializer
{
    DataSet ds;
    DataRow dr;
    Dictionary<string, Message> ms;

    MessageInitializer()
    {
        this.ms = new Dictionary<string, Message>();
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i];
            ms.Add(dr.ItemArray[0].ToString(), new Message
            {
                 Code = dr.ItemArray[0].ToString(),
                 Message = dr.ItemArray[1].ToString(),
            });
        }
    }
}
```

You can access message as follows:

```
var message = ms["001-001-001"];
```

It will be orders or magnitude faster than accessing a random `List` item:

```
var message - ms.First(x => x.Code == "001-001-001");
```

Comment: thank you so much. now how can access the single message with code? i have to use a loop. am i right?

Comment: are you sure? when I tried ms["001-001-001"] this error showed up: Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'.

Comment: My bad. I was thinking about a `Dictionary`. With `List` you can do `ms.First(x => x.Code == "001-001-001")`.

Comment: thank you so much. i red about dictionary. seems its just what i want. please edit your post and mention dictionary in it so i can marked as answer.

Comment: Yeah, added a sample that uses `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 5):

you don't need Message class any more. Using a dictionary as follows solves the problem :

```
public class MessageInitializer
{
    DataSet ds;
    DataRow dr;
    Dictionary<string, string> ms;
    public MessageInitializer()
    {
        this.ms = new Dictionary<string,string>(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count);
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i];
            ms[(string)dr.ItemArray[0]] = (string)dr.ItemArray[1];
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this would be helpful.

Comment: Would be easier this way. Unless he wants to extend `Message` later by adding new properties.

Comment: That's right my friend. In this case using a list is the solution.

Comment: But as you said above the performance of the dictionaries are much better.

Answer (score 3):

I think you just want build an array of messages from `ds.Tables[0]`

Code - 
`ms[i].Code = (string)dr.ItemArray[0];`

Message - 
`ms[i].Message = (string)dr.ItemArray[1];`

```
MessageInitializer()
{
    this.ms = new Message[ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i];
        ms[i].Code= (string)dr.ItemArray[0];
        ms[i].Message = (string)dr.ItemArray[1];
    }
}
```

For better performance make use of [Parallel.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) -

```
Parallel.ForEach(ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable(), row => {
        ms[i].Code= (string)row.ItemArray[0];
        ms[i].Message = (string)row.ItemArray[1];
});
```

Comment: currently my class work exactly like this. in order to access the message in class i have a foreach and because of millions of messages in it, it works really slow. so i decided to change the class.

Comment: @Dan do you really have to load millions of messages from you database in memory?

Comment: @AseemGautam. yes. currently it takes about 800 milliseconds to find the message and i hope i can make it faster.

Comment: @NikolaiSamteladze. unfortunately yes. i have to do it.

Comment: @Dan do you process them somehow afterwards? If so, you might want to do it in batches (say 10000 each) not to keep such large structures in memory.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to perform is the following:

```
public class Message
{
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }

}

public class MessageInitializer
{
    DataSet ds;
    DataRow dr;
    Message[] ms;

    MessageInitializer()
    {
        this.ms = new Message[ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i];
            ms[i] = new Message
            {
                code = (string)dr.ItemArray[0],
                message = (string)dr.ItemArray[1]
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dan, to find a single message by code, you ca use: var myMessage = ms.SingleOrDefault(item => item.code == someCode);